# Populate silverlight grid from a text file

Tags: c#, silverlight, grid

Friends, I have a requirement I am given a text file with fixed number of columns but row varies, I should read that and populate that in grid/table using Silverlight. The text file will have data something like this:

```
0, 0, 2, 1, "url1", description1 
1, 0, 2, 2, "url2", description2 
1, 1, 4, 2, "url3", description2
```

As we can see columns are fixed but row can vary.

Now I want my Silverlight app to read this file from system and populate in grid/table like:

```
RowNo ColumnNo Width Height ImageURL Description 

0        0       2     1       url1  Description1 
1        0       2     2       url2  Description2 
1        1       4     2       url3  Description3
```

I tried reading the file using `Streamreader` but it's showing SecurityException error `SecurityExceptionHandler was unhandled by user code File operation not permitted. Access to path "c:\path\file.txt" is denied`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access the filesystem directly for security reasons, unless the Silverlight application runs in Out-Of-Browser mode.

In a Silverlight web application, accessing the filesystem can be done only when the user initiates such an action. See [How to: Use the Open File Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221415%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on MSDN.